Wayland no longer enable-able on Ubuntu 22.04 with NVidia?

I have enabled Wayland on Ubuntu 22.04 as follows:
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf I set WaylandEnable=true
But when I run
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE it shows x11
I read that Gnome disables wayland when it detects nvidia. I disabled this as seen commented out here:

cat /etc/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules | grep WaylandEnable
# RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-runtime-config set daemon WaylandEnable false"

but that had no effect.
journald shows the following:
journalctl | grep -i Wayland
systemd[1519246]: Starting GNOME Shell on Wayland...
systemd[1519246]: org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'
systemd[1519246]: Condition check resulted in GNOME Shell on Wayland being skipped.

My system specs:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
Host: ROG Strix G834JY_G834JY 1.0
Kernel: 6.5.0-27-generic
DE: GNOME 42.9
WM: Mutter
CPU: 13th Gen Intel i9-13980HX (32) @ 5.400GHz
GPU: Intel Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics
GPU: NVIDIA RTX4090 GN21-X11
libvulkan1 1.3.204.1-2
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE -> x11
nvidia-smi -> Driver Version: 545.23.08   CUDA Version: 12.3

A few months ago, Wayland was enabled - not sure what changed.
Could this be a GRUB / initramfs issue ?
